# Arrays.asList() in Scala

Tags: scala, arraylist

Is there an equivalent to Arrays.asList() in Scala?

Or rather, how would you take a String and convert it into an Array, and then a List in Scala?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What’s the point of converting to an array and then to a list? I mean, if you’re paid by the hour, I can understand that, but otherwise?

Comment: Can you please post an example, like how would it look an example input and example output. Thank you

Comment: `"myString".toList`

Answer (score 4):

One common use of `Arrays.asList` is to produce a list containing the given elements:

```
Arrays.asList(x, y, z);
```

The Scala equivalent to that is just

```
Seq(x, y, z)
```

The other is to turn an existing array into list:

```
Arrays.asList(array);
```

In Scala, this is

```
array.toSeq
```

(note that I use `Seq` instead of `List` here; in Scala, `List` is a specific implementation, not an interface. Depending on what you want to do with it, some other type can be appropriate).

Or in many cases, nothing at all. Because `Array[A]` is implicitly convertible to `IndexedSeq[A]`, collection operations can be done directly on it without converting first.

The same applies to `String`, with a caveat that operations `List`s are good at are quite uncommon for strings, so `string.toList` is even less likely to be appropriate.